# How to load a html file using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I Have to load a html file using jquery. When i referred google, i got the snippet

$("#feeds").load("feeds.html");

But I dont want to load the content of feed.html into feeds object. Instead I need to load that page entirely.  How to load that page. Help me plz

Answer (score 4):

If you're not wanting to [load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) some HTML into an element on the existing page, maybe you mean that you want to [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery) to another page?

```
url = "feeds.html";
window.location = url;
```

Or maybe you just want to fill an entire body?  You could load() into the body tag if you wanted.

```
$("body").load("feeds.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

[$.get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get)

Here's a summary:

> Load a remote page using an HTTP GET
>   request. This is an easy way to send a
>   simple GET request to a server without
>   having to use the more complex $.ajax
>   function. It allows a single callback
>   function to be specified that will be
>   executed when the request is complete
>   (and only if the response has a
>   successful response code). If you need
>   to have both error and success
>   callbacks, you may want to use $.ajax.
>
> $.get() returns the XMLHttpRequest
>   that it creates. In most cases you
>   won't need that object to manipulate
>   directly, but it is available if you
>   need to abort the request manually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure feeds.html is located under the same domain as your script?
 If so, that line is ok, you'll search for problem anywhere else. Try to debug it with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) under Net panel.
 If not, so you are able to send only JSON requests to urls under other domains. But you can easily write a proxy script with PHP (noticed php tag under your question :) ) to load your content with cURL. Take a look at [CatsWhoCode](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-things-to-do-with-curl) tutorial at point 9, hope it'll help.